# $\text{"The error entries in the goto table are never consulted"}$ - intuitive explanation of the above claim with respect to $LR$ parsing tables

Tags: compilers, parsers

I was going through the text : *Compilers: Principles, Techniques and Tools* by *Ullman et. al* where I came across a claim:

> $\text{"The error entries in the goto table are never consulted"}$

I feel that whenever there is a reduce move, the current state pointer moves some states back. Suppose that $A\rightarrow \alpha$ is the production used and for the viable prefix $\gamma\alpha$ the current state pointer moves back those many states (so as to pop the $\alpha$ from the stack) and goes to state say $I_n$ and there is a move from $I_n$ on $A$ to some state $I_{n'}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goto table is only used immediately after a reduction action, which has just restored the parser state to the state in which the reduced non-terminal follows the dot. So the goto table for that state must have a state transition for that non-terminal; it's not an error entry.

So the error entries are never consulted.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help... [Once again :) ]